# Getting plain text instead of data from database

Tags: database, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.4.18. I am trying to get data from database. The problem is I get plan text instead of data

The code

```
public function anyData()
{
    $users = User::all();

    return Datatables::of($users)
        ->editColumn('name', function($model){
            return url('adminpanel/users/' . $model->id);
        })

        ->editColumn('admin', function($model){
            return $model->admin === 0
                ? '<span class="badge badge-info">User</span>'
                : '<span class="badge badge-warning">Admin</span>';
        })

        ->editColumn('control', function($model){
            $all = '<a href="'.url('adminpanel/users/' . $model->id . '/edit').'" class="btn btn-info">
                        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                    </a>';
        })

        ->make(TRUE);
}
```

What I should get

```
Admin
```

What I actually get

```
<a href="http://realestate.dev/adminpanel/users/2/edit">Admin</a>
```

Comment: This is what you are making here: '<a href="'.url('adminpanel/users/' . $model->id . '/edit'), so you could just swap this for the text 'Admin'. This is part of the Datatable. I don't really understand the question. Got a screenshot?

Comment: Fixed the problem by using ->escapeColumns([])